# What's the scope of Spring Controllers? It's possible to configure it?

Tags: java, spring, servlets

While experiencing weird behavior in a web application, I've found that its sessions was being invalidated and recreated everytime `HttpSession session = request.getSession();` was being executed. It was occouring specially while application calls a Spring controller built in another servlet.

As shown in the [HttpSession javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html), sessions are ServletContext. So, I ask: Spring controllers are implemented in different servlet scopes? Or just when a controller is implemented in a different servlet? Can we set Spring to maintain a single scope? Thanks!

Edit:
Adding information: I have a tip that the issue is due to I'm importing header and footer into the page. It's 90% certain that are those elements which are being processed in a different session by Spring, but I don't know how to correct this behaviour (yet).

Comment: Do you have any classes implementing `HttpSessionListener`?

Comment: No, I haven't. Session is simply being invalidated and restarted. I'm reading about Tomcat's resources limitations, that would be reseting sessions to recover it.

Answer (score 0):

session, request and response objects are not created by spring. Only the Controllers are created by spring and they are singletons by default (spring application context singletons, not JVM singletons).

So I would guess that your problem of session invalidation is happening outside of spring.

Comment: Probably is outside Spring, but I'm not achieving where it can be occouring.